# Thymeleaf href url

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying to dynamically generate links for the content in my page by looping through a list but I get 'parsing errors'

I tried as mentioned in https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html:

```
<a th:href="@{/order/{id}/details(id=3,action='show_all')}">
```

Code:

```
        <li th:each="param : ${paramList}">
            <span th:text="${placeholder}">This is displaying the value of placeholder correctly</span>

            <!-- The value I am trying to achieve is href="/member/team/ValueFromPlaceholderVariable?team=TeamName&page=PageName" -->

            <a th:href="@{/member/team/{PlaceName}(PlaceName=${placeholder},team=${param.TeamName},page=${param.PageName})}">Page</a>
        </li>
```

How can I generate the href link?

Comment: Can you try `<a th:href="@{/member/team/__${placeholder}__(team=${param.TeamName},page=${param.PageName})}">Page</a>`

Comment: What you have looks correct.  What is the error exactly?

Comment: @Metroids: Link base "/member/team/{PlaceName}" cannot be context relative (/...) unless the context used for executing the engine implements the org.thymeleaf.context.IWebContext interface (template: "intro" - line 12, col 16)

Comment: If I remove slash at the beginning then it seems to work. I need to test it more. `<a th:href="@{member/team/{PlaceName}(PlaceName=${placeholder},team=${param.TeamName},page=${param.PageName})}">Page</a>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the slash at the beginning

```
<a th:href="@{member/team/{PlaceName}(PlaceName=${placeholder},team=${param.TeamName},page=${param.PageName})}">Page</a>
```